Livewire Component Returns 404 Error After Clicking Button in Laravel
I'm working with Laravel 11 and Livewire to create a simple component that increments a counter when a button is clicked. However, when I click the "Increment" button, instead of updating the count, it returns a "404 Not Found" error.
Here’s my setup:
UPDATE ::::
"I identified the issue with the routes. When I test the following outside of this route:
it works perfectly. However, when I use it within this route, I encounter a '404 Not Found' error. The issue seems to be related to the Mcamara localization package. Is there any solution to this?"
Route (web.php):

Route::group([
    'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
    'middleware' => ['localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath', 'auth']
], function () {
    Route::get('test', function () {
    return view('livewire.test');
});
});

View (resources/views/livewire/test.blade.php):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{ $title ?? 'Page Title' }}</title>
    @livewireStyles
</head>

<body>
    <livewire:test-component />
    @livewireScripts
</body>

</html>

Livewire Component (TestComponent.php):
namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class TestComponent extends Component
{
    public $count = 0;

    public function increment()
    {
        $this->count++;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.test-component');
    }
}

Test Component View (resources/views/livewire/test-component.blade.php):
<div>
    <button wire:click="increment">Increment</button>
    <h1>{{ $count }}</h1>
</div>

When I access the test route, the page loads, but as soon as I click the "Increment" button, a 404 error is returned. I've confirmed that the button should trigger an Ajax request, but it seems like something is breaking along the way.

getting same, error

Solution in the route  :
Livewire::setUpdateRoute(function ($handle) {
return Route::post('/livewire/update', $handle);
});
